# NIMO 16.8 Expected Value + Probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Let $p=2^{16}+1$ be a prime. A sequence of $2^{16}$ positive integers $\{a_n\}$ is monotonically bounded if $1\leq a_i\leq i$ for all $1\leq i\leq 2^{16}$. We say that a term $a_k$ in the sequence with $2\leq k\leq 2^{16}-1$ is a mountain if $a_k$ is greater than both $a_{k-1}$ and $a_{k+1}$. Evan writes out all possible monotonically bounded sequences. Let $N$ be the total number of mountain terms over all such sequences he writes. Find the remainder when $N$ is divided by $p$.